# How to replace text from a string with HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, text, replace

I have the string:

```
" Text01 [1] text02 [2] text03 [3] "
```

and I need to replace the `[1] [2] [3]` with `input type="text"`

I need it for creating a **JavaScript** fill-in-the-blanks quiz.

I've done something like this:

```
$("span").click(function () 
{
    var input = $("<input>", { val: $(this).text(), type: "text" }); 

    $(this).replaceWith(input);

    input.select();
});
```

I have to add some tags between `[1] [2] [3]` and that is the part that I don't know how to do in jQuery.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... maybe something like this?

```
var str = " Text01 [1] text02 [2] text03 [3] ";

str = str.replace(/\[[0-9]+\]/g, function(match) {
    return '<span id="'+match+'"><input type="text"></span>';
});

alert(str); //outputs Text01 <span id="[1]"><input type="text" /></span>...
```

Comment: It does his job, but is not what I really want ... I want to wrap a span between [1] with an unique ID ... so that I can retrieve the value that I replaced...

Comment: Try with updated code, it sets [1], [2], or [3] to span's id.